# Hibernate - how to correctly delete a parent

Tags: java, hibernate

Ok, so I'd like to implement a simple forum example. So, I have threads, messages and users, of course and these are the pojos (I omitted the usually getters and simplicity)

**Message**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message implements java.io.Serializable, RecognizedServerEntities
{       
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "thread", nullable = false)
    private Thread thread;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "author", nullable = true)
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 31)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "body", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "Text")
    private String body;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "last_modified_date", nullable = false, length = 19)
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 19)
    private Date createdDate;
}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints =
{ @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "nick") })
public class User implements java.io.Serializable, RecognizedServerEntities
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 31)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 31)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "nick", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 31)
    @NaturalId(mutable = false)
    private String nick;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "registered_date", nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 19)
    private Date registeredDate;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = false)
    private Set<Thread> threads = new HashSet<Thread>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = false)
    private /**transient /**/ Set<Message> messages = new HashSet<Message>(0);
}
```

**Thread**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "thread")
public class Thread implements java.io.Serializable, RecognizedServerEntities
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_thread", nullable = true)
    private Thread parentThread;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "author", nullable = true)
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 63)
    private String title;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "last_modified_date", nullable = false, length = 19)
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 19)
    private Date createdDate;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "thread"/**/, orphanRemoval = true/**/)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private /**transient /**/ Set<Message> messages = new HashSet<Message>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parentThread", orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private /**transient /**/ Set<Thread> subThreads = new HashSet<Thread>(0);
}
```

I have many doubts on the annotations of course, but these are the relevant choice.

- When I delete an user, I don't want to delete all his threads and messages, so it make sense to don't use orphan-removal or cascade delete on the @OneToMany associations (ie the messages and threads collections).
- Also, because the id is automatically generated from the database, I don't think it make sense at all to use the annotation CascadeType.UPDATE (or SAVE_UPDATE) on the collections of all the entity.
- A thread are the most problematic entity to manage. When we delete a thread, we want that all its subthreads and all its messages were deleted. So, I use the CascadeType.REMOVE and orphan-removal annotations.
- An all the @ManyToOne associations, I use the CascadeType.ALL. The idea is that if we delete a message or a subthread, all the parents will be updated.
- All the collections are not transient.

Feel free to propose suggestion on this of course.

Btw, given the whole story, this is the question: suppose I have a thread "mThread" started from the user "mUser" with many messages from different users, how can I safely delete the user?
I tried different things, but I'm not sure of anything and in most cases I only have exceptions.

---

**EDIT**

I also have another class, `StorageManager<T>`, that is used to encapsulate the common code between entities. Basically, it implements the "one session per transaction" pattern. So each `methodX()` basically:

- invoke `sessionFactory.openSession()` and `session.beginTransaction()`
- invoke `session.methodX()`
- invoke `transaction.commit()`
- invoke `session.clear()` and `session.close`

Example with code

```
for (Thread t : mUser.getThreads())
    {
        t.setUser(null);
        storageManagerThread.update(t);
    }
    for (Message m : mUser.getMessages())
    {
        m.setUser(null);
        storageManagerMessage.update(t);
    }
    storageManagerUser.delete(mUser);
```

Until this point, all the table in the database have the right values. However, I don't know if it is the right way to proceed, because it leaves dirty collections.
Indeed, when at later point I try to execute some other options (e.g. `update(mThread)` or delete a message from `mThread`) a `NullPointerException` was thrown. Why is this? .

Comment: You can set all references in Thread and Message to NULL for user to be deleted and finally delete the User. However, this way you loose information on which user posted message or created thread, so maybe the better idea could be to add property to User, like 'deleted' which informs that this user was already removed. And then set that flag instead of physically deleting a user.

Comment: @dpawel09 sure, I think that the `deleted` attribute is a valuable option and certainly one that remove many problems. 
About the way to delete the use, it is what I've done in the code posted in the edit. However, I also have to update the reference first (i.e. `storageManagerX.update(X)` ) because the way I've built the storage manager class.
The problem is later on in the code, when I try, for example, to delete a message from `mThread`: a `NullPointerException` was thrown and I don't know why.